Installing GRUB in chroot to create bootable ISO
I would like to make my own live system. I have already setup a chroot environment in /home/live/chroot, but could not figure out how to install GRUB to make a bootable iso file.
After some thinking, I have come up with the following solution:
# Create and attach loopback device (such that grub has a device to install onto)
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1M count=512
mkfs.ext4 disk.img
sudo losetup /dev/loop400 disk.img

# Mount loopback device
sudo mount /dev/loop400 /mnt/loop

# Prepare chroot
sudo mount --bind /dev /home/live/chroot/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /home/live/chroot/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /home/live/chroot/sys
sudo mount --bind /run /home/live/chroot/run

# Chroot into the environment
sudo chroot /home/live/chroot

# Install GRUB
apt-get update
apt-get install -y grub-pc
grub-install --root-directory=/ /dev/loop400

But unfortunately, once I issue the last command in my chroot env, the following error occurs:
root@my-system:/# grub-install --root-directory=/ /dev/loop400
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install.

But
root@my-system:/# blkid /dev/loop400
/dev/loop400: UUID="<some_number>" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this (or does anybody know a better way of doing it)?

I'm not familiar with what you're trying to do but I know you need either MBR ('msdos') partitioning or a small unformatted `bios_grub' partition in a GPT drive in order to install then "old" GRUB for BIOS/Legacy/CSM which is the one you tried to install. For any modern system, i.e., from ~2012 or newer, GRUB for UEFI is required (and an ESP - EFI System partition, FAT32).
